# rabbitmq configuration to receive messages filtered on a pattern using single queue and many listeners

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have this requirement to push messages to a single queue but receive them at more than one place (a java class).

For that I used a topic-exchange and bound it to a queue that receives messages based on different patterns. Now when I try to receive them at the other end the listener-container send the messages to both the listeners rather than bifurcating them based on the pattern decided.

I have attached the configuration and the code below for a quick look

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest" />

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:template id="pgTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="PG-EXCHANGE"/>

    <rabbit:queue id="pgQueue" />

    <rabbit:topic-exchange id="pgExchange" name="PG-EXCHANGE">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="pgQueue" pattern="pg"></rabbit:binding>
            <rabbit:binding queue="pgQueue" pattern="txn"></rabbit:binding>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>

    <bean id="pgReceiver" class="com.pg.mq.service.impl.MessageReceiver"/>
    <bean id="txnReceiver" class="com.pg.mq.service.impl.MessageReceiver"/>

    <rabbit:listener-container id="ListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
        <rabbit:listener ref="pgReceiver" queues="pgQueue" method="handleMessage"/>
        <rabbit:listener ref="txnReceiver" queues="pgQueue" method="handleMessage"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>

</beans>
```

**Message Sender**

```
public String pushMessagePG(Object object) {
        if(object != null && object instanceof Rabbit)
            pgTemplate.convertAndSend("pg", object); // send
        return null;
    }
```

**Message Receivers**

PG RECEIVER

```
public void handleMessage(Rabbit message) {
        System.out.println("inside Message Receiver");
        System.out.println("Listener received message----->" + message);
    }
```

TXN RECEIVER

```
public void handleMessage(Rabbit message) {
        System.out.println("inside TXN Message Receiver");
        System.out.println("Listener received message----->" + message);
    }
```

**Calling Code**

```
Sender sender = (Sender) context.getBean("messageSender");
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) sender.pushMessagePG(new Rabbit(5));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) sender.pushMessageTXN(new Rabbit(2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you didn't understand the AMQP specification a bit.

1. Messages are sent to the exchange by the `routingKey`
2. Queues are bound to the exchange by the `routingKey` or `pattern` for `topic-exchange`
3. Only **single** consumer can receive a message from queue.
4. There is no mechanism like `distribution` in the AMQP. I mean something similar like `Topic` concept in JMS.
5. `topic-exchange` puts messages to all queues which `routingKey` matches to `pattern`s of the bindings.

This [article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html) describes that in the best way.

Since you bind the same queue for both patterns all messages are placed to the same queue.

From other consumers are listen on the queues and just only queues. They knows nothing about the `routingKey`.

Since you have two listeners for the same queue it isn't surprise that both of them can handle messages from that queue and it is independently of the `routingKey`.

You really should use different queues for different patterns. Or consider to use [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html) with its `Message Routing` power. You can use the standard `AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY` (Spring Integration) header for that case.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification Artem. I am new to AMQP, actually to Messaging Queue implementation to be precise. I am currently using the pattern per queue design as you have mentioned. But in that case i have to create a queue each time a routing key is added. I was trying to achieve the same result using a single queue for at least similar patterns like pg.rom.* and pg.com.*

Comment: I actually read the same article you mentioned to tutor myself on this concept. And have learned the queue per pattern design from there using which I'm currently using in my application.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: several patterns for the same queue, but there is no automatic routing on the consumer side: it just poll message from the queue. This is your concern.

Comment: Yes exactly, I was looking for a possible way to filter messages based on the pattern when they are polled from the queue and be sent to appropriate receivers rather than simple polling to the bound receivers as you mentioned.